# Angular 4 Data Table not showing correct footer info

Tags: angular

When Angular 4 data table displays records, the record count is not showing, I access here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-4-data-table. This plugin is a fork of Angular 2 data table here: https://ggmod.github.io/angular-2-data-table-demo/, so i assume the table would have the correct footer info as here https://ggmod.github.io/angular-2-data-table-demo/.

**html template**

```html
<p>
    <button class="btn primary"><a routerLink="./new">New</a></button>
</p>
<p>
    <input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."> 
</p>
<data-table
    [items]="items"
    [itemCount] = "itemCount"
    (reload) = "reloadItems($event)"
>
    <data-table-column
    [property] = "'title'"
    [header] = "'Title'"
    [sortable] = "true"
    [resizable] = "true"
    ></data-table-column>
    <data-table-column
    [property] = "'price'"
    [header] = "'Price'"
    [sortable] = "true"
    [resizable] = "true"
    >
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
        {{item.price | currency:'USD':true }} 
    </ng-template>
    </data-table-column>

    <data-table-column
    [property] = "'$id'"
    >
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
        <a [routerLink]="['./', item._id]">Edit</a>
    </ng-template>
    </data-table-column>
</data-table>
```

In my typescript file I checked to make sure that itemCount is always defined.

```js
private initializeTable(products: Product[]) {
    this.products = products;
    this.tableResource = new DataTableResource(products);
    this.tableResource.query({offset: 0})
      .then(items => this.items = items);
    this.tableResource.count()
      .then (count => {
        alert('count ' + count);
        this.itemCount = count;
      });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Angularjs is the wrong tag for your question. Read the tag info of both tags.

Comment: Did you initialize the itemCount variable? itemCount = 0;

Comment: yes, i initialized it and updated as data was loaded as per code i posted, alert always showed a value. after updating to angular 5, I started getting Metadata version mismatch for module found version 4, expected 3, which i could not resolve. I ended up just copying and pasting the source code into my project to get it to work, as i could not find any compatible package configuration that would work.